# How can I add a feature that user can delete own data

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a "Phone-book" and with a login panel. After a user logs in, they can add their phone numbers.

The part I am having trouble with is trying to add new functionality allowing users to delete their phone numbers from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a column like user_id. and save the id of the user who added the phone number. so after that you can check if the logged user id is equal to the  user_id then it can be deleted

Comment: like if(Auth::user() =$id)   is it true??

Comment: if(Auth::id() == $id)

Comment: thanks__________